# Is there a way in RSpec to return the double object itself on doubles?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there an native way in RSpec to return the double object itself on doubles?

I'm hoping for something like `double(:relation, active: myself, in_batches: myself, each_record: [record])`.

It obviously is possible by assignment and spreading over multiple lines:

```
relation = double(:relation, each_record: [record])
allow(relation).to receive(:in_batches).and_return(relation)
allow(relation).to receive(:active).and_return(relation)

relation
```

The code under test, can then use this as standin for method chains like `Foo.active.in_batches.each_record`.

I could not find anything in RSpec docs and code, but may have missed something crucial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the messages in bulk via [`receive_messages`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/basics/allowing-messages#messages-can-be-allowed-in-bulk-using-%60receive-messages%60):

```
relation = double(:relation, each_record: [record])
allow(relation).to receive_messages(in_batches: relation, active: relation)
```

There's also [`as_null_object`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/basics/null-object-doubles) which returns the double in response to arbitrary messages:

```
relation = double(:relation, each_record: [record]).as_null_object

relation.in_batches.active.each_record #=> [record]
relation.foo.bar.baz.each_record #=> [record]
```

Comment: `as_null_object` is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. A weird name, though: I would not have expected `null_objects` to be for message-chains.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any one-liner like this. It's hard to suggest anything as it's not clear how you exactly intend to use this double... so the following might be a total miss for you.

You mention

> The code under test, can then use this as standin for method chains
> like Foo.active.in_batches.each_record.

Maybe you could simplify the problem and test the outcome of the method instead of implementation details?

Let's say this is the method under test:

```rb
def do_stuff
  Foo.active.in_batches.each_record do |foo|
    foo.update bar: 1
  end
end
```

you could test it like this

```rb
let!(:active_foo) { create :foo, :active }
let!(:another_active_foo) { create :foo, :active }
let(:other_foo) { create :foo, :inactive }

specify do 
  expect { do_stuff }
    .to change(active_foo, :bar).from(nil).to(1)
    .and change(another_active_foo, :bar).from(nil).to(1)
end

specify do
  expect { do_stuff }.not_to change(other_foo)
end
```

But (as you probably already noticed) there's a slight issue with such a test: one could change the method like this.

```rb
def do_stuff
  Foo.active.each do |foo|
    foo.update bar: 1
  end
end
```

And the tests would still pass. I'd add assertion like this:

```
expect(Foo).to receive_message_chain(:active, :in_batches, :each_record).and_call_original
```

To explicitly communicate that this is required behavior.

Comment: That is an entirely different way of testing, though. It leans towards integration testing. I want to unit-test, not test that "active record works as expected" (it does, I know for sure); I want to test that I'm calling the right methods on the direct neighbours, and on doing so, get the expected output. Thanks for your reply, though. But it suggests a solution that is not in scope of the question.